# Error - Unable to load ai model in c# application

Tags: c#, onnx

I tried to run a c# application which use an image classification model, but when I try to load the image, the program crashes with the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The parameter is incorrect.
> Failed to load model with error: Unknown model file format version.'

This is the function that loads the model into memory:

```cs
private async Task loadModel()
{
    // Get an access the ONNX model and save it in memory.
    StorageFile modelFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/Model.onnx"));
    
    // Instantiate the model. 
    modelGen = await Model.CreateFromStreamAsync(modelFile);
}
```

Comment: The second line of error description says it all. It looks like the model file you are trying to feed in is not compatible with the code. Are you sure about the model file that you are providing as parameter is the correct one? Also, I see it resides on network path. Can you try downloading it on local disk and see if it gets read successfully?

Comment: I tried to read the file from a local path, but i get the following error: "System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))'
"

Comment: Please read the [description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ml/info) of the ML tag.

Comment: @CezarMarcu : You need to get that access problem resolved first. It looks like your program is trying to read the file on the first line, failing to do so, creating an empty 'modelFile' object, which in turn was throwing the 'invalid file' error. Right click on your file, check all security permissions and make sure there are enough permissions present on that file.

Comment: @CezarMarcu : You need to get that access problem resolved first. It looks like your program is trying to read the file on the first line, failing to do so, creating an empty 'modelFile' object, which in turn was throwing the 'invalid file' error. Right click on your file, check all security permissions and make sure there are enough permissions present on that file.